# Weird Behaviour of Oracle 11g to 12C

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g, oracle12c

My application runs select sql queries using JDBC driver on Oracle and stores the data in Result set. Then by using buffer writer/file writer writes information to xml.

** Weird Behaviour : Same code when runs with Oracle 11g takes 2 hrs to complete and for 12 C it takes @ 12 hrs.

** JDBC driver I am using is compatible with 11g and 12c. Data is same on both the DBs. Both DB are independent instance, so no question of migration problems. 
 Can somebody please help, what how can I debug for this ?

** select queries uses bind parameter IN clause and has 1000 values in it.

Comment: Try to run your query directly on both instances (using some client sqlplus, toad etc..) in order to check - is it java  & driver problem ..or db problem.

Comment: Most likely, Oracle 12c chooses a different, slower execution plan than 11g. This is the kind of difference you would always expect when upgrading to a new database version. Use a client tool (Toad, SQL Develeoper, SQL*plus etc.) to retrieve the execution plan on each system and compare them.

Comment: AWR report is also worth checking

Comment: It could also be differences in memory allocated to the 12c db - for example, when we migrated our 10g solaris db over to 11g Linux ASM, we lost out on a lot of file / system caching that solaris handled for us, meaning that our SGA and/or PGA (I forget which) was woefully undersized over on the 11g instance. Bumping that up to 32GB (instead of the 2GB it had been previously!) massively improved performance. Most likely, you're experiencing a combination of the things that have been suggested so far

Answer (score 0):

IT seems, there is a bug with Oracle 12C.  Working with Oracle support.